# Cant access eximstats sqlite3 db after WHM64 upgrade

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite, cpanel, whm

After WHM 64 upgradation, cant access eximstat db. MySQL code changed to PDO for accessing sqlite3 db as follows:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3', DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

The failues, defers tables are all blank. In fact, a new blank file was getting created in the var/cpanel directory, instead of getting connection to eximstats db. Surprisingly, CPanel:'View Sent summary' fetch information all correctly,  But I cant access in my script which is residing on the domain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

During a chat with the excellent support of cPanel, we figured out this:

It is a problem with rights for eximstats_db.sqlite3 table: you are trying to access the database as a non-root user, but database is owned by root and only writable by root.

In theory you should be able to access the file directly by passing the SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY flag to the call to open the file as outlined here:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php

So granting read access to eximstats_db.sqlite3 tables (NB! there are 3 of them):

```
-rw----r-- 1 root root 135168 Jun 10 06:06 eximstats_db.sqlite3
-rw----r-- 1 root root 32768 Jun 12 14:34 eximstats_db.sqlite3-shm
-rw----r-- 1 root root 1058512 Jun 12 14:34 eximstats_db.sqlite3-wal
```

and using

```
$dbh = new SQLite3('/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3',SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
```

should work, but it doesn't. It appears to be a limitation with the SQlite3 library within PHP: even for read-only access it wants to lock access to the file. So you need to give them also write access:

```
-rw----rw- 1 root root 135168 Jun 10 06:06 eximstats_db.sqlite3
-rw----rw- 1 root root 32768 Jun 12 14:34 eximstats_db.sqlite3-shm
-rw----rw- 1 root root 1058512 Jun 12 14:34 eximstats_db.sqlite3-wal
```

That's that. After that, you'll see the defers, failures and other tables.

(Of course, in real life you might want to create a group and give read-write access to that group only, not everybody).

---

If you are not able to change permissions to these database files then the only solution I can see is to copy the files to domain, change the permissions there and then use these files instead:

```
$target = '/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3-shm';
$newfile = '/home/yourdomain/where/your/script/is/eximstats_db.sqlite3';
copy($target, $newfile);
chmod($newfile, 0777);
// same with all 3 files..
$dbh = new SQLite3('eximstats_db.sqlite3'); // not '/var/cpanel/eximstats_db.sqlite3'!
```

Comment: Dear so-called @Konservin,

Thanks a lot for the valuable input. But in my case, the 'root' user has full permission on the db file and the piece of code you suggested is throwing an exception 'Unable to open database: unable to open database file'.

Thanks

Comment: @MithaVivek are you sure that you're connecting as a root? You say "I cant access in my script which is residing on the domain." And AFAIK, SQLite doesn't have a concept of username/password, so how can you say that you're root? BTW Did you try changing the permissions for these 3 files?

Comment: As we have limitations in granting write permission to database, we are in a situation to hold this requirement. Hope, we will get this solved on next update.Thanks a lot dear friend.

Comment: In that case try copying the files to where you can change the permissions, and use a cron job. (I also updated the answer.)

Comment: this temporary approach wont work out as our script always get this warning 'Permission denied'/''Access Denied' on any attempt to access it. I had tried is_file already. :-(